# cmake not working on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, makefile, g++

I'm trying to build OpenCV 3.0.0 on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian Jessie. After installing all dependencies, I tried running cmake with the following parameters: `cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++ -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`

But then I got the following error.

```
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:112:
Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  End of file reached.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/release/CMakeFiles/3.0.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:119:
Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "".
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/release/CMakeFiles/3.0.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:221:
Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  End of file reached.
CMake Error: Could not process cmake module file: /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:40 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".cxx" for file

    /home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:

    C CXX

  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:88 (project)


-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:88 (project)


CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:113:
Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  End of file reached.
CMake Error: Could not process cmake module file: /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the symlink `/usr/bin/c++` is there? Try `/usr/bin/g++` directly

Comment: Yes I tried it with `/usr/bin/g++` aswell and got the same error. `/usr/bin/g++` points to `g++-4.9`.

Comment: Try to compile any c++ program using g++. If you succeed, I don't know what it can be

Comment: I tried to compile a simple hello world program with g++ and it worked. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually a solution, but I reinstalled my Raspberry Pi again, but this time with the older Raspbian version "Wheezy". On Wheezy, everything worked fine. So I guess there's a problem with Raspbian "Jessie" with OpenCV and/or cmake.